# Compile error concerning variables (scope?) in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, scope

Consider this example:

```
<% int testNumber = 1; %>
//Some HTML goes here
<%=testNumber%>
```

I get compile error:

```
testNumber cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: You are not importing int class.(java.lang.Integer). Writing Java code inside JSP is not a good way.

Comment: @vikiiii If I do everything in a single pair of <% %> then it works. Amit Bhargava - That is the content of my test.jsp file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that you understand variable scoping. It's in *scriptlets* the same as in normal Java classes.

So if you *actually* have for example

```
<%
   if (someCondition) {
       int testNumber = 1;
   }
%>

...

<%=testNumber%>
```

Then you will get exactly this error (also in a normal Java class!). To fix this, you'd need to make sure that the variable is declared in the very same scope, if necessary with a default value.

```
<%
   int testNumber = 0;

   if (someCondition) {
       testNumber = 1;
   }
%>

...

<%=testNumber%>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, using *scriptlets* is considered [poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/).

Comment: What if I need HTML to go between declaration and variable use?

Comment: It should not matter. The point is that the variable needs to be declared in the same scope as where you need to access it. You've apparently declared the variable in a different and narrower scope (e.g. inside `if` or `for` block, etc) while you're trying to access it from outside. It's not different from in a normal Java class. Using a normal Java class is only easier to understand and maintain the code.

Comment: BalusC, thanks for the link. It contained a lot of useful info I had no idea about. In that case I will have to rewrite my code to remove all/most scriptlets.

Answer (score -1):

Design problems aside, try declaring the variable as a global:

```
<%! int testNumber = 0; %>
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea! Instead of a local variable in the service method this gets placed as a member on the servlet class. Threads will mess this up on concurrent requests. Servlets are not thread safe so you will get into issues if you add state to a servlet instance.

Comment: I never said it was a good idea (and I also mentioned this in the foreword to the answer), just suggested an alternative solution for the particular problem in question, leaving it up to the OP to decide.